# forcing this to indicate the desired object inside forEach statement

Tags: javascript

Here i have a programme which count a persons different daily activities like how many times he played football in a week etc.Here i have a switch statement which counts values of different activities.I forced THIS object to indicate the `dayEvents object` inside `sort()` function.But inside the `forEach method` its indicating the global object.Also an error is saying that football is not defined.why is that so??I couldn't figure out how can i force THIS to indicate the same `dayEvents` object??

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
(function(){
var dayEvents={
    football:0,
    school:0,
    video_games:0,
    watch_tv:0,
    coding:0,
    container:[],
    insert:function(evt){
        this.container.push(evt);

    },
    get:function(){
         sort.call(this); 
    }
}
function sort(){

   for(i=0;i<this.container.length;i++){


         this.container[i].forEach(function(elements,index,array){

                switch(elements){
                    case football:
                        (this.football)++;
                        break;
                    case school:
                        (this.school)++;
                        break;
                    case video_games:
                        (this.video_games)++;
                        break;
                    case watch_tv:
                        (this.watch_tv)++;
                        break;
                    case coding:
                        (this.coding)++;
                        break;                      

                 }

          });


   }

}
dayEvents.insert(['football','school','video_games','watch_tv','coding']);
dayEvents.insert(['football','school','coding']);
dayEvents.insert(['school','video_games','watch_tv','coding']);
dayEvents.insert(['football','video_games','coding']);
dayEvents.insert(['school','watch_tv','coding']);
dayEvents.insert(['football','school','video_games','watch_tv','coding']);
dayEvents.insert(['football','school','video_games','coding']);
dayEvents.get();
console.log(dayEvents.football);
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your switch cases should be strings I.E `case "football" .. case "school"` etc.

Comment: @George: Yeah, probably. It's technically valid, if he has `football`, `school`, and such variables. (JavaScript's `switch` is unlike Java's or C's, the values of cases can be expressions), but I think you're probably right... :-)

Comment: Of course, but it's clear to see where the OP is heading in this particular case ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply the second argument to `forEach`, which is called `thisArg`; it will use that as `this` during callbacks to your iterator.

I think you're looking for having `this` the same inside calls to the iterator as outside, so:

```
  this.container[i].forEach(function(elements,index,array){
    /* ...contents omitted for brevity... */
  }, this);
// ^^^^^^
```

Alternately, you could use a bound function via `Function#bind`, but as `forEach` specifically gives you `thisArg`, that's probably the way to go. (All of the other ES5 array additions have it as well, FYI — `some`, `every`, `reduce`, ...)

---

Separately, as George points out in a comment on the question, the values of your `case` labels are a bit suspicious:

```
case football:
```

That's *valid* in JavaScript, if you have a variable named `football` (this may surprise some people!), but looking at your code I suspect you probably wanted:

```
case "football":
```

...and similarly for the others.

Comment: what's the difference between football & "football"??

Comment: @user3138436: In this context, `football` is a variable reference; if you don't have a variable by that name, you'll get a `ReferenceError` when you try to use it. `"football"` is a string.

Comment: thanks!! if you excuse me i have another question.If i set THIS to be dayEvents object inside sort() function using sort.call(this) then why we need to set this again for forEach seperately??

Comment: @user3138436: Because how `sort` is called is irrelevant to the `forEach` call. `sort.call(this)` sets `this` to be the same during the call to `sort` as it is in the code calling `sort`. That doesn't have any effect on what `this` is in the callback for `forEach`, which is why you have to tell `forEach` what `this` to use during the callback.

Answer (score 1):

To get desired object as this in forEach loop you need to pass that object as the second paramter in forEach function.
You are getting that error at line 'case football:' in switch case. Because football is not a variable, you need to use it as a String.

Please use the code as below.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
(function(){
var dayEvents={
    football:0,
    school:0,
    video_games:0,
    watch_tv:0,
    coding:0,
    container:[],
    insert:function(evt){
    this.container.push(evt);

    },
    get:function(){
         sort.call(this); 
    }
}
function sort(){

   for(i=0;i<this.container.length;i++){


         this.container[i].forEach(function(elements,index,array){
                console.log(this);
                switch(elements){
                    case 'football':
                        (this.football)++;
                        break;
                    case 'school':
                        (this.school)++;
                        break;
                    case 'video_games':
                        (this.video_games)++;
                        break;
                    case 'watch_tv':
                        (this.watch_tv)++;
                        break;
                    case 'coding':
                        (this.coding)++;
                        break;                      

                 }

          }, this); //instead of 'this', you can also pass 'dayEvents'


   }

}
dayEvents.insert(['football','school','video_games','watch_tv','coding']);
dayEvents.insert(['football','school','coding']);
dayEvents.insert(['school','video_games','watch_tv','coding']);
dayEvents.insert(['football','video_games','coding']);
dayEvents.insert(['school','watch_tv','coding']);
dayEvents.insert(['football','school','video_games','watch_tv','coding']);
dayEvents.insert(['football','school','video_games','coding']);
dayEvents.get();
console.log(dayEvents.football);
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if it works